# Get Data from Firebase Firestore in Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to get data from firestore in functions of firebase Node JS 8.

I receive a QueryDocumentSnapshot which is totally fine but i cannot get data from this.

I want androidNotificationToken but i get error undefined.

I am tring this

```
    const missing_owner = snapshot.data().missing_owner;
const found_owner = snapshot.data().found_owner;

console.log("Missing Owner",missing_owner); //this is working


const missRef = admin.firestore().collection(`users`).doc(`${missing_owner}`);
const foundRef = admin.firestore().collection(`users`).doc(`${found_owner}`);

const doc1 = await missRef.get();
const doc2 = await foundRef.get();

console.log("Data is ",doc1); //this is also working


const androidNotificationTokenMisser = doc1.data().androidNotificationToken; //cant get this 
const androidNotificationTokenFounder = doc2.data().androidNotificationToken; // and this
```

Comment: Can you share the **entire** code of your Cloud Function? Are you sure your Cloud Function is declared as `async`?

Comment: I have tried to run this is node 8, but unsuccessful due to different error. However node 8 is  deprecated so maybe I should use some old dependencies. Anyway in node 10 its working with no problem. Maybe you should migrate to Node 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some problem with fetching the string with name androidNotificationToken from the firestore, so I renamed it to token and now it is working.